Using a shared library in a declarative Jenkins pipeline
I have a declarative pipeline that I want to use classes from a a shared library in.
I have declared a libraries block as follows:
libraries {
    lib('app-engine-jenkins-lib')
}

… but I do not know how to reference the classes in the shared library in script blocks in my steps. The only way I can get it to work is explicitly define the library in my script block, as shown below:
lib = library('app-engine-jenkins-lib').any.old.com.utils
Object issues = lib.GitUtils.getIssues(...)

But… as far as I can tell… this makes defining the libraries block irrelevant.
Is anyone able to provide any guidance?

What provides libraries step? I'm not aware of any plugin that would do that.

You should be able to declare it at the top:
@Library("app-engine-jenkins-lib") _

Then reference it later in a stage:
stage('Stage name'){
    steps{
        functionInsideLibrary(paramters)
    }
}


Thanks for coming back to me.
I can give that a go... but I was trying to stick to doing everything within the pipeline block.
Also, it still begs the question of what use the libraries block is in a declarative pipeline.

@MartinSmithson there is no libraries block in Jenkins pipeline syntax and the suggested solution is a go-to thing for both declarative and scripted pipelines.

@AlexanderPletnev That is interesting... because there is a libraries section in Chapter 7. Declarative Pipelines of the the Jenkins 2: Up and Running book that states:
One of the newer directives introduced in Jenkins for Declarative Pipelines is the libraries directive. This directive allows Declarative Pipelines to import shared libraries so that code contained in them can then be called and used.
